# .NET Core Razor Pages OnPostAsync Success Reload PartialView on Another Page

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I have a page /Product.cshtml

Product.cshtml has a PartialView _ProductAlisasList.cshtml

**Product.cshtml**

```
<div id="product-aliases-container">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/Product/_ProductAliasList.cshtml", Model.Product.ProductAliases)
</div>
```

_ProductAliasList.cshtml can open /ProductAlias/Edit.cshtml in a popup.

When /ProductAlias/Edit.cshtml OnPostAsync succeeds, I want to reload the _ProductAliasList.cshtml on the Product.cshtml page.

**/ProductAlias/Edit.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.Attach(ProductAlias).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!ProductAliasExists(ProductAlias.ProductAliasId))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    //HERE I WANT TO RELOAD THE PARTIALVIEW _ProductAliasList.cshtml ON THE /Product.cshtml PAGE

}
```

Comment: What's your Product.cshtml look like ? You may need ajax to "RELOAD THE PARTIALVIEW _ProductAliasList.cshtml ON THE /Product.cshtml PAGE" .

Comment: @QingGuo the relevant code from Product.cshtml is in the original post.  I agree ajax is likely how I will need to reload the PartialView, but I'm unsure of how to accomplish this from Edit.cshtml.cs

Comment: In the OnPostAsync() you can use `return PartialView("_ProductAliasList",yourmodel);`  to return the data ,then in the ajax success function use     `$('#containerId').html(data);` to show the data (_ProductAliasList.cshtml ON THE /Product.cshtml PAGE).